# Why is my GCP Vertex pipeline api_endpoint not right?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

My `API_ENDPOINT` is set to `europe-west1-aiplatform.googleapis.com`.

I define a pipeline:

```
def pipeline(project: str = PROJECT_ID, region: str = REGION, api_endpoint: str = API_ENDPOINT):
```

when I run it:

```
job = aip.PipelineJob(
display_name=DISPLAY_NAME,
template_path="image classification_pipeline.json".replace(" ", "_"),)
job.run()
```

it is always created in USandA:

```
INFO:google.cloud.aiplatform.pipeline_jobs:PipelineJob created. 
Resource name: projects/my_proj_id/locations/us-central1/pipelineJobs/automl-image-training-v2-anumber
```

How do I get it into Europe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `location` parameter in the `aip.PipelineJob()` class can be used to specify in which region the pipeline will be deployed. Refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/aiplatform#class-googlecloudaiplatformpipelinejobdisplayname-strhttpspythonreadthedocsioenlatestlibrarystdtypeshtmlstr-templatepath-strhttpspythonreadthedocsioenlatestlibrarystdtypeshtmlstr-jobid-optionalstrhttpspythonreadthedocsioenlatestlibrarystdtypeshtmlstr--none-pipelineroot-optionalstrhttpspythonreadthedocsioenlatestlibrarystdtypeshtmlstr--none-parametervalues-optionaldictstrhttpspythonreadthedocsioenlatestlibrarystdtypeshtmlstr-any--none-enablecaching-optionalboolhttpspythonreadthedocsioenlatestlibraryfunctionshtmlbool--none-encryptionspeckeyname-optionalstrhttpspythonreadthedocsioenlatestlibrarystdtypeshtmlstr--none-labels-optionaldictstrhttpspythonreadthedocsioenlatestlibrarystdtypeshtmlstr-strhttpspythonreadthedocsioenlatestlibrarystdtypeshtmlstr--none-credentials-optionalgoogleauthcredentialscredentialshttpsgoogleapisdevpythongoogle-authlatestreferencegoogleauthcredentialshtmlgoogleauthcredentialscredentials--none-project-optionalstrhttpspythonreadthedocsioenlatestlibrarystdtypeshtmlstr--none-location-optionalstrhttpspythonreadthedocsioenlatestlibrarystdtypeshtmlstr--none) for more information about the `PipelineJob()` method.

```py
REGION = "europe-west1"

job = aip.PipelineJob(
          display_name=DISPLAY_NAME,
          template_path="image classification_pipeline.json".replace(" ", "_"),
          location=REGION)

job.run()
```

The above code will deploy a pipeline in the `europe-west1` region. The code returns the following output. The job is now deployed in the specified region.

```
INFO:google.cloud.aiplatform.pipeline_jobs:Creating PipelineJob
INFO:google.cloud.aiplatform.pipeline_jobs:PipelineJob created. Resource name: projects/<project-id>/locations/europe-west1/pipelineJobs/hello-world-pipeline
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `location = API_ENDPOINT` in `google.cloud.aiplatform.init`.